# ElasticSearch : Number of indices supported in search across multiple indices

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to search across multiple indices as follows:

```
GET http://localhost:9200/index1,index2/type1,type2/_search
```

It is working fine. I want to know if there is any limit on number of indices we can specify in URL.

**Note :** I cannot use any pattern for specifying indices, the only option is the pass the indices names in the URL.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a default upper limit of 4kb on the [max length of an HTTP URL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html). Make sure either to fit the list of indices and types under this, or increase the default value of parameter `http.max_initial_line_length`

Comment: Thanks Rahul ! that was really useful

Answer (score 1):

There **was** a limitation of 1000 shards until Elastic 5.3 ([source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/search-search.html)), which no longer existing.

It clearly states this:

> Searching one index that has five primary shards is exactly equivalent to searching five indices that have one primary shard each.

And this:

> By default elasticsearch doesn’t reject any search requests based on the number of shards the request hits.

As the default `total_shards_per_node` value is unbounded, I would say the only limits are your server's ones.

Comment: Thanks zessk for the prompt response !! I am using ElasticSearch 5.1 and 1 shard per index , so looks like I can't specify more than 1000 indices in search query

Comment: By default, yes. But you still can increase the `action.search.shard_count.limit` value (this is highly discouraged).